# JSON autocomplete, doesn't show results

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I am trying to implement JSON for the first time, for an autocomplete input type.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
function searchFailed(){
$("#searchresults").html("Sorry, there was a problem with the search.");
}
    $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source") });
    });
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("QuickSearch", "Search", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET", OnFailure = "searchFailed", LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader", UpdateTargetId = "searchresults", }))
{
<input type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("QuickSearch", "Search")" />

}
```

But it is complaining that data-autocomplete-source is not a valid attribute. It goes into the QuickSearch but I don't see a autocomplete result.

Answer (score 0):

```
 target.data("autocomplete-source");
```

use the data attribute. jQuery.[data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

---

Replace:

```
$("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
    var target = $(this);
    target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source") });
});
```

with:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({ source: target.data("autocomplete-source") });
    });
});
```

You using `$(function () {})` to wait until the page is "ready" and the element exists.

---

Change:

```
<input type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("QuickSearch", "Search")" />
```

to:

```
<input class="my-autocomplete" type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("QuickSearch", "Search")" />
```

And change:

```
$("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each
```

to:

```
$("input.my-autocomplete").each
```

Comment: Where do I have to add the target.data?

Comment: It is calling my action. But I don't see the results of the action in a suggestion list?